# CodeIgniter submit items from select

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a select like this:

```
$stuff=$this->Database->getItems();
$data['mySelect']=form_multiselect('addedStuff[]', $stuff, '1', 'id="addedStuff" multiple="multiple"');
```

When I submit the form and then POST all the values of the select I have this:

```
$var = $this->input->post('addedStuff');
var_dump($var);
```

And the var_dump shows:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string '0' (length=1)
  1 => string '1' (length=1)
  2 => string '2' (length=1)
```

My problem is that I don't want to have numeric strings, I want the text of my selected items. They should look like this:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string 'IMP 291B' (length=8)
  1 => string 'IMP 9891' (length=8)
  2 => string 'IMP 492' (length=7)
```

getItems:

```
function getItems()
    {
        $query = $this->db->query(sprintf (GET_PRINTERS_MODELS));

        $results=array();

        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
        {
          array_push ($results, $row['modelo']);
        }
        return $results;
    }
```

My select shows correctly in the view...

How can I solve this?

Comment: Post your model too `getItems();`

Comment: what does `var_dump($stuff)` look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the keys of your `$stuff` array to your values, try this:

```
$stuff = $this->Database->getItems();
$stuff = array_combine($stuff,$stuff);
$data['mySelect']=form_multiselect('addedStuff[]', $stuff, '1', 'id="addedStuff" multiple="multiple"');
```

Answer (score 1):

I see two solutions.

1) You change `$stuff` to have keys identical to the values.

CodeIgniter's  form_multiselect just like form_dropdown generates the options such that the keys of the passed option list contains the value for the corresponding option text.
Ergo before the multiselect you do:

```
$stuff = array_combine($stuff,$stuff);
```

2) Because approach 1 might or might not mess up any sent data, you keep the indices, but make a lookup in the receiving controller based on the indices. As follows:

```
$stuff=$this->Database->getItems();
$var = $this->input->post('addedStuff');
$var = array_intersect_key($stuff,$var);
```

The second approach feels safer..